# Sending MS Outlook mail from Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet, its have several internal code (gs) and finish doing a list with mails and text, actually Im using a function to send mails:

```
function SendMail () {
  var vAuxiliar = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Auxiliar");
  var vLast = vAuxiliar.getDataRange().getNumRows();  

  var vDataRange = vAuxiliar.getRange("A2:E"+vLast);
  var vValues = vDataRange.getValues();

  for(var i in vValues) {
    var vemailAddress = vValues[i][1];
    var vMensaje = vValues[i][4];
    var vSubject = 'Contact.';

    MailApp.sendEmail(vemailAddress, vSubject, vMensaje);
  };    
};
```

Its works great but mails are incoming with my personal account, I need change this function to send mails with my enterprise account, we use MS Outlook, it is possible?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "enterprise account, we use MS Outlook," Besides clarifying this please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi Ruben, I mean a company account, not gmail or hotmail.

Comment: That is not enough. Perhaps you should ask to your company email service admin if it's enabled the use of external cloud services to send emails from your company email service. If so, also they should tell you what are the alternatives (what APIs are enabled, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You sure cannot use the Gmail service to send messages through your MS Outlook account.

But a possible workaround would be to create aliases for your MS Outlook account in your Gmail account, and then using this alias when sending.

```
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to, 'Subject', 'A message sent from an alias!', {'from': "enterprise@example.com"});
```

But for using this `from` parameter in [`sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) you need to be able to retrieve it as an alias with [`getAliases()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getaliases).

Refer to [this page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) to add your enterprise mail as an aliases to be able to use later.

Note that using the term *alias* here refers to the Gmail terminology as *external email address*. Do **not** check *"Treat as alias"* when configuring your MS Outlook account. This is [another story](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1710338?hl=en).

---

Also as Ruben said in the comments you could try to ask if there are any API you can use to send mail. In that case you should try to use the [URL fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) method.